# Illuminate\Foundation\Application::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given

Tags: installation, laravel-5

I am a fresh starter in laravel. On my fresh installation of laravel 5 I am getting this....any help??

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Application::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\app.php on line 16 and defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php on line 108
```

Comment: did you run: 

composer install  

?

Comment: How have you installed laravel5? Have you tryed the Github clone? and just like thisisablock said, dont forget the composer install or perhaps the composer update if your sourcecode is a bit older...

Comment: yes, I cloned it from github and run the composer install.
And this error is after that.